# I accidentally deleted python3.6 from my ubuntu-18.04, and now when I reboot my computer it requires username and password and gets me shell

Tags: python, python3

I deleted python3.6 from my ubuntu-18.04 by doing.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python3.6
```

Now, when I reboot computer it asks for username and password and gives me shell. How do I solve this.

I tried to do.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

but it gives an error.

[ERRER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XLAW.jpg)

I can not find a way to solve this. Please help!

Comment: It seems in the shell you have no internet connection. How do you usually connect to the Internet? If WIFI ... could you attach a cable ?

Comment: Have you also tried fixing missing?

Comment: Yes, I did. Did not help. Internet seems to work fine, I have windows as well in the same PC, I checked the internet, it there. May be there is a way to connect to the internet from shell?

Comment: Try recovery mode > Enable networking and then Drop to root shell prompt.

Comment: Brings the same thing:(. I am ok to lose my files, I don't have anything important there, can I somehow, completely uninstall Ubuntu and then install it again from scratch when I am in this condition?

Answer (score 1):

I have also encountered this problem recently， so here is my solutions.

The above error is because the connection is **not available**, so you can not use `apt install` command directly. The key point to connect to network can refer [Configure WiFi Connections](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/configure-wifi-connections), maybe you should **reboot** your ubuntu after doing this.

Then you can run the command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`, it may take a few minutes.

Finally, I hope to help you guys who have also encountered the same problem.